# Get max Underscore.js with comparison

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

Is there is a way to get maximum time values with comparison of user_id and assess_id with the help of underscore.js, So user_id and assess_id are kind of composite

list would be

```
var list = [
      {user_id: 316,asess_id:1,time:1418109860},
      {user_id: 316,asess_id:1,time:1417708379},
      {user_id: 316,asess_id:1,time:1417708231},
      {user_id: 316,asess_id:2,time:1417708379},
      {user_id: 316,asess_id:2,time:1417692420},
      {user_id: 5092,asess_id:2,time:1417692141},
      {user_id: 316,asess_id:1,time:1417633200},
      {user_id: 5092,asess_id:1,time:1417633200},
      {user_id: 448,asess_id:1,time:1417633200}
    ];
```

required answer would be

```
var answer = [
      {user_id: 316,asess_id:1,time:1418109860},
      {user_id: 316,asess_id:2,time:1417708379},
      {user_id: 5092,asess_id:2,time:1417692141},
      {user_id: 5092,asess_id:1,time:1417633200},
      {user_id: 448,asess_id:1,time:1417633200}
    ];
```

Although i know one solution that i loop through whole list and start filling answer and while entering data in answer check for duplicate value i already implemented this solution. Want to learn is it possible with the help of Underscore.js

Comment: Whats the relation between user_id and asess_id ?

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking, what is your question?

Answer (score 1):

You can use combination of groupBy and map/max methods:

```
var result = _.chain(list)
    .groupBy(function(el) {
        return el.user_id + ',' + el.asess_id;
    })
    .map(function(obj) {
        return _.max(obj, 'time');
    })
    .value();
```

Check the test demo below.

```js
var list = [
    {user_id: 316,asess_id:1,time:1418109860},
    {user_id: 316,asess_id:1,time:1417708379},
    {user_id: 316,asess_id:1,time:1417708231},
    {user_id: 316,asess_id:2,time:1417708379},
    {user_id: 316,asess_id:2,time:1417692420},
    {user_id: 5092,asess_id:2,time:1417692141},
    {user_id: 316,asess_id:1,time:1417633200},
    {user_id: 5092,asess_id:1,time:1417633200},
    {user_id: 448,asess_id:1,time:1417633200}
];

var result = _.chain(list)
    .groupBy(function(el) {
        return el.user_id + ',' + el.asess_id;
    })
    .map(function(obj) {
        return _.max(obj, 'time')
    })
    .value();

alert(JSON.stringify(result, null, 4));
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.7.0/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `_.groupBy(list, 'user_id')` first. Then you sort the sub-arrays by whatever criteria you can define on asess_id and time and reduce the array again.

```
var grouped = _.groupBy(list, 'user_id');

var selected = _.reduce(grouped, function(result, value, key) {
  result[key] = _.max(value, 'time');
  return result;
}, {});
```

If you call `_.values(selected)` on this, you'll get:

```
[
  {
    "user_id": 316,
    "asess_id": 1,
    "time": 1418109860
  },
  {
    "user_id": 448,
    "asess_id": 1,
    "time": 1417633200
  },
  {
    "user_id": 5092,
    "asess_id": 2,
    "time": 1417692141
  }
]
```

Try it out: http://jsfiddle.net/687f6suh/